# How to pass duration for discriminant ada?

Tags: ada, duration

I'm playing around with ADA, trying to get my grips on it. I still have a hard time figuring out the discriminant part though. I have a task with one discriminant, and I'm trying to pass a duration to it. However it tells me:

```
package Procedures is
   task type WhatchDog(dur : Duration := 1.0) is
      entry Reset(start : in Time);
      entry Sync(timedOut : out Boolean);
   end WhatchDog;
end Procedures;

with Procedures;
procedure Main is
   watch : Procedures.WhatchDog(dur => 0.5);
begin
   null;
end Main;
```

> Discriminants must have a discrete or access type.

When I change my discriminant type to an access type,

```
task type WhatchDog(dur : access Duration := 1.0) is
```

it gives me the following warning:

> Expected an access type with designated type "Standard Duration"
>
> Found type universal real

I know there are other ways to realize a constructor, such as creating an entry point. But I would like to know what I'm doing wrong here, and understand the error I'm making.
The google work I've done so far doesn't really shine any light on this, and only makes use of real types which seem to work fine. Here for example:
http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/docs/95style/html/sec_6/6-1-3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you cannot assign `1.0` to `dur` (the access discriminant) is that `dur` is of a pointer type (anonymous, access to `Duration`) while `1.0` is a numeric literal. In short, you cannot assign a real value to a pointer variable, only a pointer value to a pointer variable. See [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39372498/4449975) for one way to get one.

The type `Duration` is not a discrete type, i.e. neither integral nor enumerated. But discrete is what a discriminant must be if not of an access type, given discriminants' original intent as outlined by [manuBriot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39385708/4449975).

So, to initialize some aspect of task objects by passing a value for `dur`, you need pointers. The following small rewrite does not use an allocator (**new**), it uses names for duration values, of which it then takes the pointer using `'Access`.

```
package Procedures is

   Duration_By_Default : aliased constant Duration := 1.0;

   task type Whatchdog
     (dur : access constant Duration := Duration_By_Default'Access)
   is
      entry Reset(start : in Time);
      entry Sync(timedOut : out Boolean);
   end WhatchDog;
end Procedures;

with Procedures;
procedure Main is
   Desired_Duration : aliased constant Duration := 0.5;

   watch : Procedures.WhatchDog(dur => Desired_Duration'Access);
begin
   null;
end Main;
```

Note the implications of having an access value point to a variable duration, instead of a constant duration as shown here.

Alternatively, perform a computation that produces a `Duration` value from some integer discriminant, named `dur_in_msec`, say.

```
task body Whatchdog is
   dur : constant Duration := Duration(Float(dur_in_msec) / 1_000.0);
```

Comment: Thank you for the in depth example and the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

In your attempted workaround you're trying to assign a Duration to an Access. The proper assignment would be, if going that way:

```
task type WatchDog (Dur : access Duration := new Duration'(1.0)) is
```

at the price of having an allocation that is never deallocated, that is, a minor memory leak. That could be a problem if you create/destroy many instances of the task type during a long-lived program, but in that case you have to also take care of reaping the tasks (at least in Gnat).

In this case, I would either have a first entry to pass the Duration value  to the task, or a value in milliseconds (or whatever is appropriate) using a Natural as discriminant, and converting it inside the task. Certainly it is an itch in the language.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure this is the intended use of discriminants. Here, `duration` is really a configuration of your instances, but doesn't impact the layout of the type in memory. So I think it would be better (and certainly more usual) to either have a `Configure` entry that can be called to do the initial setup, or if this really needs to be given when the instance is created, you could try creating a `generic` with a formal `Duration` parameter.

Comment: I know creating an entry point is the better way to do it, but I'm trying to understand the discriminant feature :)